# Alarm system built with raspberry + sonoff rf bridge

Tags: raspberry-pi, power-sources

I am developing a personal project at the end of which I should be able to create a homemade alarm system.

All this should be protected against voltage drops/failures, the whole circuit will be inside a "box" that I will print with the 3d printer.

To be precise, the project foresees these components:

- Raspberry Pi 0 with Domoticz (80 mA / 0.4 W)
- Sonoff RF Bridge with Tasmota (30 ~ 200mA/3.0 ~ 3.6V)
- Buzzer
- Step up circuit (optional)

I'm looking for a circuit that works as an "UPS/backup battery", which allows me to keep the system running for as long as possible (1h would be the top).
A PC UPS (just to be clear) must be excluded as a solution, power banks apparently are not good as manufacturers advise against charging them and powering devices at the same time.

I have tried circuits like [this](https://www.amazon.it/dp/B07DJYW6HY) but they are very poor, the battery does not hold up and unfortunately the charge readings through the GPIO are not realistic.

[image: DollaTek Cappello ups con Batteria per Raspberry Pi 3 Modello B / 2B / B + | Adattatore Batteria | Fonte di Alimentazione Pi 3]